# Adding timediff to output

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a query in php for a mysql database and have successfully run a loop to retrive the information I require.
However, part of my output requires an additional query to output the timediff of two fields and I cannot get that to echo properly. $billable works correctly just can't echo the additonal line to add the time difference to the table

```
$billable = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM responses WHERE company ='XXXXXX' && date  BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' && time_arrived >0 && TIMEDIFF(time_arrived, time_received)< 2500", $connection); 
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($billable);

$time_diff = mysql_query("SELECT TIMEDIFF('time_received',time_arrived')FROM alarmresponses WHERE company ='XXXXXXX' && date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' && time_arrived >0 && TIMEDIFF(time_arrived, time_received)< 2500 AS value_sum
", $connection); 
$elapsed = mysql_num_rows($time_diff);

while ($bill = mysql_fetch_array($billable)){


echo"<p style='page-break-before: always'>
<table>

<tr><td><p style='text-align: right;'>SCHEDULE B</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p style='text-align: right;'>Page 1 of 1</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p style='text-align: center;'>XXXXXXX</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p style='text-align: center;'>SERVICE RESPONSE REPORT</p></td></tr>

<tr><td>Property Owner's Name</td</td>".$bill['name']."</td><td>DATE</td><td>".$bill['date']."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Address</td><td>".$bill['address']."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Type of SERVICE</td><td>".$bill['type']."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Time Received:</td><td>".$bill['time_received']."</td><td>Time Arrived<td><td>".$bill['time_arrived']."Time Clear:</td><td>".$bill['time_cleared']."</td></tr>";

echo"<tr><td>Total Time Elapsed:"***.$elapsed['value_sum'].***"Minutes00:00</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select it in your query otherwise it will not be part of your result set:

```
$billable = mysql_query("SELECT *, TIMEDIFF(time_arrived, time_received) AS time_elapsed FROM responses WHERE company ='XXXXXX' && date  BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' && time_arrived >0 && TIMEDIFF(time_arrived, time_received)< 2500", $connection); 

echo $bill['time_elapsed']; // get the value and print it
```

FYI, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, here is [good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).